# 2d dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, 2d

I'm having trouble creating a 2d dictionary. I have searched this website as well has numerous others and cannot find anything to help me with my issue!

I need to create a 2d dictionary that sorts data based on two distinguishing factors, animal and breed. The data is imported from a csv file. I start off sorting each line of the file into a 2d list where each entry is data for one animal/breed combination.

```
    for line in file:
        entries = line.split(',')
        list.append(entries)
```

This part works fine and gives me a well-organized list. My problem arises when trying to sort this list into a 2d dictionary based using animal and breed names as the types. So mydict['animal']['breed'] would give me a list of stats about the animal and breed combination. mydict['cat'] would list out all the breeds associated with cats and the list values mapped to each. My problem is I can only get one breed for every mydict['animal']. Here is an example of one of my attempts. I'm trying to do this without importing any supplementary dictionaries.

```
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        #animal type is first element of the list
        key = list[i][0]
        #breed is second element of the list
        breed = list[i][1]
        animal_dict.set_default(key, {})[breed] = list[i][2:]
    print(animal_dict['cat'])
```

when I run this I get:

```
{'Siamese': ['15 years', 'No', 'Yes', '165']}
```

This is the very last breed entry for cats in the file, so my dictionary is overriding every breed entry as it loops through the list. Any suggestions on how to fix this? 
Sorry for the ambiguity in parts of this - I can only explain so much without the actual input file to reference.

Comment: It would help if you gave example data. Oh, and you should **never** use the name `list` as it is the name of the built-in function `list`.

Comment: Also, are you sure `"cat"` is the only key being used? No random spaces like `" cat"` and `"cat "` and `" cat "` which would all be different keys?

Comment: Give example data and expected output.

Comment: In other words, your code *should* work (albeit it is not very idiomatic). There must be something up with your data.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga list is not the actual name in my code, I just changed some things around for clarity!

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer

This line is writing over your old data:

```
animal_dict.set_default(key, {})[breed] = list[i][2:]
```

Use append instead of an assignment here.  You'll need to create an empty list to append to first.

#### Long answer

It's not very Pythonic to make an index and then use it to loop through the list - just go through the elements of the list directly!  Let's call your list `animals` and your output dict `animal_dict`:

```
animal_dict= {}
for animal in animals:
    species = animal[0]
    breed = animal[1]
    stats = animal[2:]
```

This isn't the slickest way to do it, but it's simple.  Now, we need to make sure we have the species in the dictionary.  A simple way to do it is:

```
if species not in poke_dict:
    animal_dict[species] = {}
```

Now we check if `breed` is in *this* dictionary.  If not, we make it:

```
if breed not in animal_dict[species]:
    animal_dict[species][breed] = []
```

Finally, now that we're sure our dict has the correct animal and breed keys, we can add our new entry with `append`:

```
animal_dict[species][breed].append(stats)
```

Putting it together, with some test values:

```
animals = [
    ['cat', 'Siamese', '15 years', 'No', 'Yes', '165'],
    ['cat', 'Bombay', '15 years', 'No', 'Yes', '165'],
    ['dog', 'Labrador', '15 years', 'No', 'Yes', '165'],
    ['cat', 'Siamese', '15 years', 'No', 'Yes', '165'],
    ['dog', 'Poodle', '15 years', 'No', 'Yes', '165'],
]

animal_dict= {}
for animal in animals:
    species = animal[0]
    breed = animal[1]
    stats = animal[2:]
    if species not in animal_dict:
        animal_dict[species] = {}
    if breed not in animal_dict[species]:
        animal_dict[species][breed] = []
    animal_dict[species][breed].append(stats)
print animal_dict['cat']
```

The construction

```
if species not in animal_dict:
    animal_dict[species] = {}
if breed not in animal_dict[species]:
    animal_dict[species][breed] = []
```

is clumsy, and can be replaced with `setdefault` like this:

```
animal_dict= {}
for animal in animals:
    species, breed, stats = animal[0], animal[1], animal[2:]
    animal_dict.setdefault(species, {}).setdefault(breed, []).append(stats)
print animal_dict['cat']
```

If there's only one instance of each animal/breed combination:

```
animal_dict = {}
for animal in animals:
    species, breed, stats = animal[0], animal[1], animal[2:]
    animal_dict.setdefault(species, {}).setdefault(breed, stats)
print animal_dict['cat']['Bombay']
```

Output:

```
{'Siamese': [
   ['15 years', 'No', 'Yes', '165'], 
   ['15 years', 'No', 'Yes', '165']
], 
'Bombay': [
   ['15 years', 'No', 'Yes', '165']
]}
```

Comment: Don't show the OP a method which uses the unpythonic `if key not in dictionary: dictionary[key] = {}`. OP was already using `setdefault` which is how you *should* do this. Indeed, it would be even better to use a `defaultdict`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga agreed, and my answer has been modified. It could be done as a dictionary comprehension too, which I'd say is going too far.

Comment: I would recommend `defaultdict` or `setdefault`. I still don't think you are answering the right question: the OP is only getting one *breed*, not one set of data associated with the breed. Indeed, I'm assuming each species-breed combination occurs once.

Comment: If each combination occurs once, this method will still work (though of course the return value will be a list of lists.  It just also supports the possibility that it could happen more than once.

Realistically, it made sense to me that there could be multiple Siamese cats, or Labrador dogs.  Answer modified again, though.

Comment: My point is that the OP has not posed a well-defined question. Your answer makes an assumption about the problem that only the OP can answer...

Comment: Thank you so much! your explanation was exactly what I needed. Altered a bit to match my code, but it worked perfectly!